# Have you strayed?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does " have you strayed" mean in the following video ?

Because there is no direct context and the word has a few meanings, it is hard to tease the meaning out

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6Kkq7xULSo&list=PL3F6BC200B2930084&index=5

time : around 2:10

Answer (score 1):

The video talks about commitment and how the human nature helps (or interferes with) keeping it.

"*Strayed*" here means "*broke your promise*", "*wandered off straight-and-narrow*".

Basically "*have you strayed*" means "*have you broken your promise*", "*have you violated your commitment*".

Comment: ok.cheers @Victor Bazarov